# PHP - Sort Two Arrays The Same Way

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, text, numeric

I have two different arrays. One array, a, for a list of people. My other array, b, for a list of their ages. I go to sort b by number and then reverse it so it goes in descending order. I got to this part okay.

How do I sort a (a list of people's names) so that the same values are still paired up with the sorted list?

Example:

a contains Bob, Sue, Phil, and Jenny respectively

b contains 15, 12, 13, and 13 respectively.

I want my outcome to be:

a contains Bob, Jenny, Phil, and Sue respectively

b contains 15, 13, 13, and 12 respectively

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

using example #1 in the reference:

```
$a = array('Bob', 'Sue', 'Phil', 'Jenny');
$b = array(15, 12, 13, 13);
array_multisort($a, $b);
print_r($a);
> Array
 (
 [0] => Bob
 [1] => Jenny
 [2] => Phil
 [3] => Sue
 )
print_r($b);
> Array
 (
 [0] => 15
 [1] => 13
 [2] => 13
 [3] => 12
 )
```

Comment: If using array_multisort their corresponding ages won't match.

Comment: Please add context to the link you've provided.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I cannot seem to get this to work.

Comment: bfavaretto answer would be the great answer for me if he really wants the two array to be combine and match up with their correct ages.

Comment: @MarCejas, agreed, but the answer is yours, I just added an example :)

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use:

```
$arr = array('Bob'=>15,'Sue'=>12,'Phil'=>13,'Jenny'=>13);
```

Then you can sort smoothly.

Comment: Example: `$c = array_combine($a, $b); asort($c);`

Comment: having array structured this way will also make it simple and scalable.

On this structure you can reverse the array http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php or sort the array http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php using php functions and not worry abt how to reflect the changes to your other aray

Comment: What if you have two Jennys?