# Manipulating arrays of dates in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm having a lot of difficulty approaching a piece of code in `PHP`. I have an array of dates and values, for example

```
dates = (2014-12-01,2014-12-02,2014-12-08,2014-12-09,2014-12-10,2014-12-11)
values = (5,3,7,8,9,2)
```

You'll note that `12/01` is a Monday, as is `12/08`. I'd like to form 4 arrays from these two arrays:

```
monday = (5,7)
tuesday = (3,8)
wednesday = (0,9)
thursday = (0,2)
```

You'll note that the arrays are formed by grabbing the values associated with the days of the week. However, in the case that a Wednesday date exists, for example, but the prior Tuesday does not, then the array should have a "0". In other words, the 4 arrays should all be the same length.

Can anyone help me write code in PHP to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

**NOTE**: So far, I have only determined how to find the day of the week from a date: `date('l', strtotime("2014-12-08"));` I really can't figure out the general algorithm to solve this.

Comment: Have you made an attempt yet? It would be helpful to see it.

Comment: The explanation is unclear

Comment: A general algorithm: Iterate through the `date` array. For each date's key/value, determine the day of the week. Add the value for the same key from the `values` array to an array with a key that corresponds to the day of the week.

Comment: @showdev thanks a lot for your idea. I'm a little bit confused, however. Do you think you could write php code to do this? For example, what happens when a "Monday" is encountered and then the next date is also a "Monday". It seems more complicated than what you wrote.

Comment: You can append to the "week" array: `$weekdays[$day_of_week][]=$values[$dates_key];` I'm sorry, I don't want to write all the code -- nothing personal. But the SO community will help to troubleshoot your code if you make an attempt and have trouble.

Comment: What do the values in the new array correspond to actualy?

Comment: @DarkBee, they are taken from the "values" array. Each date corresponds to a value.

Comment: Ow index wise u mean :)

Comment: @DarkBee yeah, index wise, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates  = array( '2014-12-01','2014-12-02','2014-12-08','2014-12-09',
                 '2014-12-10','2014-12-11' );
$values = array( 5, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2 );

$date  = strtotime(min($dates));
$stop  = strtotime(max($dates));
$dates = array_flip($dates);
$out   = array();

while($date <= $stop)
{
   $tmp = date('Y-m-d', $date);
   $out[date('l', $date)][] = isset($dates[$tmp]) && isset($values[$dates[$tmp]]) ?
                              $values[$dates[$tmp]] : 0;  
   $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date);   
}

print_r($out);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 7
        )

    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 8
        )

    [Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 9
        )

    [Thursday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
        )

    [Friday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [Saturday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [Sunday] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

)
```

ps: `how can I get the an array of all the dates included in the "dates" array associated with only all the Mondays?`

Modify the code as, for example:

```
   $tmp = date('Y-m-d', $date);
   $exists = isset($dates[$tmp]) && isset($values[$dates[$tmp]]);
   $out[date('l', $date)]['numbers'][] = $exists ? $values[$dates[$tmp]] : 0; 
   if ($exists) $out[date('l', $date)]['dates'][] = $tmp;
   $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date);
```

You'll get an output as (example for monday)

```
[Monday] => Array
    (
        [numbers] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => 7
            )

        [dates] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2014-12-01
                [1] => 2014-12-08
            )

    )
```

Comment: @CodeGuy not sure what you are talking about. `$monday = $out['Monday'];` .. and so on?

Comment: thanks so much!! Sorry, I was trying to ask: how can I get the an array of all the dates included in the "dates" array associated with only all the Mondays?

Comment: great, thanks! One last thing: this assumes the dates are in order. What if the dates aren't in order such that the dates and associated indices should be sorted. How could I do that?

Comment: @CodeGuy My code does not care about order of the dates as long as $values and $dates correspond to each other. But if you really need it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9917886/1164491

Comment: @CodeGuy give me example of data. It should not depend on the order. or are you looking at the values in `[dates] => Array`? Check the link above.

Comment: I misspoke. That's why I deleted it, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better way to get the `0`s in there without another loop but I'm headed out:

```
foreach($dates as $key => $val) {
    $day = date('l', strtotime($val));
    $result[$day][] = $values[$key];
}
foreach($result as &$val) {
    if(count($val) == 1) {
        array_unshift($val, 0);
    }
}
print_r($result);
```