# double $ (variable of variable) doesn't print the variable value as a variable

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$dates = array('2014-12-01','2014-12-02','2014-12-08','2014-12-09','2014-12-10','2014-12-11');
$values = array(5,3,7,8,9,2);

foreach ($dates as $date){
 //Array of the regarded days names is generated
  $days[] = strtolower(date('l', strtotime($date)))."\n";
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($days); $i++){
 $day = $days[$i];    
 $$day = $values[$i];
}    
echo $monday;
?>
```

`echo $monday` does not print any value, I expect it to print 8, because in the last loop I had a variable named with the value of `$day` and the last setting for that value should be 8. So why it does not set correctly?!

This is a demo: http://codepad.org/VDIyBuq3

Comment: Deja vu?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452960/manipulating-arrays-of-dates-in-php/27453291

Comment: I don't ask about the regarded question itself. I just ask about other implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$days[] = strtolower(date('l', strtotime($date)))."\n";
                                                 ^^^^^ here
```

You are adding a new-line character to the end of your value, so your value will not be `monday` but `monday\n`.

Just remove that:

```
$days[] = strtolower(date('l', strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- A bit bored I guess ;-)

Comment: Hahaha!! You know me ;) Always the *perfectionist*